# Send file with curl command in C#

Tags: c#, curl

I have to send a file since a cURL command :

```
curl -X POST -F "csv[file]=@/mypath.csv" https://mylogin:mypassword@the-server.net
```

Si i tried with an HttpClient :

```
       var client = new HttpClient();


        // Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
        var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("csv[file]", $@"@/{this.pathFile}")});

        // Get the response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($@"https://{this.login}:{this.password}@myserver.net",requestContent);

        // Get the response content.
        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

        // Get the stream of the content.
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {
            // Write the output.
            var testResult= await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
```

Or with the following code :

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create($@"https://{this.login}:{this.password}@myserver.net");
        // Set the Network credentials
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = $@"csv[file]=@/{this.pathFile}";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        using (WebResponse response2 = request.GetResponse())
        {
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response2).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
```

But each time, it's the result 401 Unauthorized. Of course, my credentials are the good ones...

[EDIT]

I work for a professional project. the server where to send the file belongs to a partner. The cURL command is imposed on me and i haven't got control of this server

[EDIT 2]

I did an analysis with wireshark

- IP 229 is the partners server
- IP 160 is my compuer

[image]

I just have an encrypted alert. I tested with HTTP and not https but i have the same message

Comment: I guess the curl-command itself works. Then we can exclude errors like no access with the credentials, no connection or errors in the command itself you try to translate to C#. Have you tried to analyse the sent command by curl via Fiddler or Wireshark for all the sent information or some other thing curl does?

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like that the file you are accessing is placed at a point where the user did not have any right to access the file, Try to give permission to the folder of read and write access to use the file.
That could solve your issue.

Comment: I work for a professional project. the server where to send the file belongs to a partner. The cURL command is imposed on me and I'm not in control of this server